# Convert JSON to bash environment variables

Tags: json, node.js, bash, env

I wrote this beauty a while back to run on a server and convert environment variables from `JSON` to a bash `.env` format.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var strings = []
process.stdin.resume()
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8')
process.stdin.on('data', function(data) {
  var json = JSON.parse(data)
  for (var key in json) {
    var val = json[key]
    strings.push(key + '="' + val + '"')
  }
})
process.stdin.on('end', function() {
  var output = strings.join('\n')
  process.stdout.write(output)
})
```

Can this be done without node, just bash? I'm having trouble getting this working on a server without node installed or without the correct path specified.

Comment: I don't know what this code is doing, you should specify it. To handle JSOn in bash, use jq --> https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: I need a command / file / bash script that will process STDIN JSON and STDOUT each key value pair  in the format `key + '="' + val + '"'` followed by a new line.

Comment: @fedorqui I cant use any dependencies that aren't already native to ubuntu / linux / unix.

Comment: As @fedorqui suggested, use a JSON processor. Bash is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein as I just said, I can't have any dependencies.

Comment: Then you can't do this; standard Unix utilities just aren't cut out for parsing JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, assuming that all the key/val pairs you want to keep are in the form:

```
"key":"stringval"
"key":numval
"key":true or false or null
```

(with optional space around the colon):

```
#!/bin/sh
tr -d '\n' |
  grep -o '"[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]\+"\s*:\s*\("[^"]\+"\|[0-9\.]\+\|true\|false\|null\)' |
  sed 's/"\(.*\)"\s*:\s*"\?\([^"]\+\)"\?/\1="\2"/'
```

Example:

```
cat manifest.json | ./json2env.sh
```

yields

```
name="Polymer Starter Kit"
short_name="Polymer Starter Kit"
src="images/touch/icon-72x72.png"
sizes="72x72"
type="image/png"
test1="0.123"
test2="true"
test3="false"
test4="null"
```